# Can't increase ThreadPoolExecutor's core pool size

Tags: java, multithreading, kotlin, concurrency, threadpoolexecutor

I'm having issues *dynamically* increasing the core pool size of a ThreadPoolExecutor in kotlin.

First I define my ThreadPoolExecutor like this:

```
val POOL = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20) as ThreadPoolExecutor
```

Then I add some tasks to the ThreadPoolExecutor.

After some time, *in a different thread*, while the tasks are still running:

```
POOL.corePoolSize += 20
```

It returns:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.setCorePoolSize(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1545)
    at MainKt.main$lambda-1(Main.kt:95)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

The weirdest part is, it works fine if I do this:

```
POOL.corePoolSize = 40
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, the maximum pool size *MUST be greater than or equal* to the core pool size as indicated in the `setCorePoolSize()` method:

```java
if (corePoolSize < 0 || maximumPoolSize < corePoolSize)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
```

Basically instead of:

```
POOL.corePoolSize += 20
```

It should be:

```
POOL.maximumPoolSize += 20
POOL.corePoolSize += 20
```